# Execute a method at given time (with threads)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I would like to execute a method at a given time (e.g. every day at 7 PM). My first idea was to check the current `TDateTime` every second with a `TTimer`, but it is not thread safe. How should I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319461/delphi-alarm-clock-like-application

Comment: I would use the OS and a scheduled task

Comment: An alternative to use if you need to do this in an existing service is to use waitable timers - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for basics. There is a Delphi example by Remy at http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/201102/11020811353.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the OS and configure a scheduled task which launches the Delphi application at the given time.