# Looking for an event scheduler for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, jedi

I was recently looking at TJvScheduledEvents that comes with the JVCL library because I have a need for a dynamic scheduler in a Delphi application.  Initially this looked to fit the bill, but I have run into some concerns.

- Limited documentation other than the code itself
- The event scheduler form that lets you create events appears to be a design time form with no runtime interface.
- Issues with storing dynamically created scheduled events to a file or database so that they are not lost when the application restarts.

Does anyone have any experience with this object or another scheduling interface.  I would rather not have to build this myself if there are other options.

Comment: Take a look at [CRON Scheduler](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cron-scheduler/). I prefer this type of solution rather than delegating the schedules to the windows scheduler.

Comment: Here is a similar question : [How to get a delphi application (that's running) to do something at a particular time/date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2037527/576719). And here : [Delphi 'Alarm Clock'-like application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8319461/576719).

Comment: With regard to your third point, `TJvScheduledEvents` will store and load it's events automatically if you assign a `TJvAppStorage` to it's `AppStorage` property (and set the `AppStoragePath` to the proper folder). `TJvAppStorage` is on the component palette as well (I don't recall which tab, but you should be able to find it). You can also look at `TJvSchedEvtStore`, in the `JvSchedEvtStore.pas` file.

Comment: For the project, I selected CRON Scheduler as the best integration piece.  Thanks for the comments.  However, I'm still looking for a scheduler app that has a nice recurring schedule creation dialog, but perhaps not as rich as the DevExpress component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [CRON Scheduler](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cron-scheduler/) as referenced in the comments above by @LURD.  It has worked as expected and was very easy to integrate.  I also like that it cleanly supported threads for running scheduled events and fit what I was looking for.

Comment: Cron Scheduler is great! And Looks like TScheduledEvent.Name is the only way to pass parameters to the OnScheduleEvent, is it correct?