# Calculating next nearest date time matches with wildcards

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, delphi

I stuck with a strange algorithm. Looks simple but not. 
User can give a task execution date in wild-carded format. And I should execute the task at given date on a low power embedded platform.

There are two approaches to achieve the problem:

- My MCU can wake up every second and check whether current date matches with any of wild-carded date. If it is, then execute the task. This solution is simple but consumes lots of power because of waking up every second.
- Other solution could be, If I could calculate next task execution date exactly, I could schedule my embedded platform to wake up at that pre-calculated specific date and execute it immediately at that time. This will save more power because whole platform during that time will be in sleep mode.

My problem started with calculating next action date time.

For example, given execution dates could be:

1. `FFFF/FF/FF FF:FF:FF` means that any years/any months/and days any hours/any minutes/any seconds. I meant simply that execute the task ever seconds.
2. `FFFF/FF/FF FF:FF:00` means that the task has to be executed every minutes
3. `FFFF/FF/01 02:00:00` means that every first day of the month at 2 o'clock
4. `2014/FF/15 FF:00:00` means that every hours on 15th day of any months during 2014 only.
5. `FFFF/02/FF 00:00:00` means that every days of February at midnight
6. `FFFF/01/01 04:30:00` means that every beginning of the year at 4:30

Examples can be grown but I believed that I explained the problem.

I need an algorithm which takes current date as first parameter and user wild-carded date as second parameter and it should calculate and return the next execution date. Next execution time of the task should be calculated without using while loop. (because it has to be fast and deterministic in time)

For people who wonder what I did (with while loop unfortunately which is almost same like waking up ever seconds):

as Algorithm:

```
1: Increment Current Date by a second
2: Check if it matches with wildcarded pattern
3: Goto 1 if it is not matching.
```

in Delphi:

```
function DoesDateMatchWithPattern(const pattern: string; const dt: TDateTime): Boolean;
Var
  year, month, day,
  hour, minute, second,
  ms: Word;

  syear, smonth, sday,
  shour, sminute, ssecond : String;

begin
  Result := True;
  DecodeDateTime(dt, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, ms);

  // decode patten items
  // 1    6  9  C  F
  // FFFF/FF/FF FF:FF:FF
  syear :=    Copy(pattern, 1, 4);
  smonth :=   Copy(pattern, 6, 2);
  sday :=     Copy(pattern, 9, 2);
  shour :=    Copy(pattern, 12, 2);
  sminute :=  Copy(pattern, 15, 2);
  ssecond :=  Copy(pattern, 18, 2);

  // any non wildcarded sections have to match, otherwise returns false
  if (syear <> 'FFFF') and (StrToInt(syear) <> year) then
    Result := False;

  if (smonth <> 'FF') and (StrToInt(smonth) <> month) then
    Result := False;

  if (sday <> 'FF') and (StrToInt(sday) <> day) then
    Result := False;

  if (shour <> 'FF') and (StrToInt(shour) <> hour) then
    Result := False;

  if (sminute <> 'FF') and (StrToInt(sminute) <> minute) then
    Result := False;

  if (ssecond <> 'FF') and (StrToInt(ssecond) <> second) then
    Result := False;
end;

function CalculateNextDateTime(const pattern: string; out next_date_to_execute: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  last_possible_date : TDateTime;

begin
  Result := false;

  last_possible_date := EncodeDate(2099, 12, 31);

  // takes current date time
  next_date_to_execute := Now();

  while (next_date_to_execute <= last_possible_date) and (not Result) do
  begin
    // calculate next second
    next_date_to_execute := IncSecond(next_date_to_execute);

    // check if it matches with the pattern given
    Result := DoesDateMatchWithPattern(pattern, next_date_to_execute);
  end;
end;
```

As I indicate previously I need a solution loop-less and deterministic in time.

Any suggestion as pseudo algorithm or name of the problem -so that I can search for it- or any idea are accepted.

Thank you.

Comment: Downvoters, let me see your thoughts.

Comment: Hovering your mouse over the vote buttons w/should give you the answer to that. I didn't downvote, but I presume you are being downvoted because you are asking people to do your work for you. The first question anyone who is likely to help would ask is: "what have you tried?" You are not showing any research or effort.

Comment: Well, they are totally wrong then. I can update the question to show where I stuck exactly in my code but I don't want people dig my code, the problem is not related with the code. I believe that the question is a standard problem which has a name but I don't know yet. I just need an idea for the algorithm, a name or a direction that's it. I wonder how people solved such problems.

Comment: @MehmetFide Please read [this part](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of the help center to get a clue why you get the downvotes. I did not downvote, but I was going to vote for close as being off-topic before your edit. Well lets see ...

Comment: To avoid the `while` loop, determine the needed year, then the needed month, then the needed day, etc.  Code has at most 6 tests.

Comment: it is not simply replace wildcards with current one situation. Suppose wildcard is FFFF/FF/15 FF:30:00 and today is 2014/04/26 15:25. Next date should be 2014/05/15 00:30:00. All the cases you need math with numbers, strings are not enough if this is you point.

Comment: Pity about the down-votes because this seems an interesting problem, even if the SO format doesn't suit is very well. You asked how to describe the problem: googling "delphi scheduler with wildcard support" seems to produce some useful-looking hits.

Comment: Do you need support for wildcards on minutes or seconds after specific hours and/or minutes? I.E. `FF/FF/FF 13:FF:00` Every minute during  the 14th hour of every day?

Comment: @MartynA: Yes I agree, a bad case of trigger happiness on the part of some SO participants. It was at -6 at some stage. Happy to see it getting some up-votes now.

Comment: Oh, by the way, have you looked at (googled) calculating recurring calendar events for inspiration?

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Any parts including seconds can be wildcarded. Your case is posible as well. Actually there are more wildcards for day of month and day of week such as last day of month, second last day of month or for any specific day of week which I didn't mention here at all. Incrementing by a second and checking with the pattern yields always correct answer but very slow.

Comment: I did not dig into your specific timing problem, but I found a CRON component good for similar problems. The good thing is that it can provide an event, no polling needed. Wildcards on most timing parameters possible. See [Looking for an event scheduler for Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10270660/576719).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a CRON scheduler, see wiki information: [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

It permits to schedule jobs at intervals, or based on specific timing with wildcards.

You can find a Delphi component implementing this logic in another SO question, [Looking for an event scheduler for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10270660/576719).

No polling needed, just add a timing logic string and an event to call.

Comment: Finally we came to the point. CRON was the thing I was looking for. I suffered a lot to explain what I needed but worthed. I will check how they implemented in CRON Scheduler and try to follow same in my embedded platform.

Comment: @MehmetFide: If you know the first occurrence and the recurrence pattern, the algorithm is a lot easier than matching any time to some wildcarded pattern. See [Recurring Events](http://allenbrowne.com/apprecur.html) for information. The meat of the algorithm in that article is in an `iif` statement in one of the queries. You will have to download the access database (bottom of the page) and inspect that query's definition using MS Access (or Excel?). Your problem then boils down to calculating the next occurrence and taking the result as the starting point for the next calculation.

Comment: @Marjan: Yes but it is not mandatory to be in a form of periodic recurring. Actually the keyword here was "CRON" which I didn't heard about it before. I found many resources after that. One of them is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321494/calculate-when-a-cron-job-will-be-executed-then-next-time?rq=1

Comment: @MehmetFide: Cool. Thanks for the link! Out of curiosity I was working on a (naive) solution. That post really helps.

Comment: "Finally we came to the point." It took so long because the question was not clear.

Comment: Sorry but it seems that it was clear for somebody. I have provided all data that I had at that time in order to come to the point.