# Delphi + start a web-service (short PHP program) and transfer XML file back to Delphi (= me)

Tags: delphi

At 10:00 o'clock I switch to the Twebbrower form in my running Delphi application. Types the URL of my web-server (eg: http://www.myserver.com/test2/COPY_MY_SQLBASE_TO_XML.php and clicks RUN), which - as the name imply - creates a XML-copy of the existing MY_SQLbase. No feed-back neccessary. Just a simple Web-request. After that back "to normal" ...

15 minutes later I start a FTP from Delphi and transfer the XML-file (SQL_BASE_AS-XML.XML) back to me. (15 minutes to make sure it has been done ! )

I wonder:  Is it possible to automate that and how do I do that (if possible)?

(saves place, executes faster and less code (I hope))

Comment: Does not seem to be a Delphi question. Why don't you put your application in the task scheduler?

Comment: @mg30rg - Why task-scheduler ? It is just an ordinary Delphi program/application  .. with a little bit of future ...

Comment: Well if you don't want to use task scheduler, thew best way to go is to write a windows service which performs the same operation on a daily basis. But that is sort of "reinventing the warm water".

Comment: Or of course you might write a long-running application. Your server could even have a callback where you can gather status information to be able to display a Progress indicator.

Comment: If you only need to run the task at the scheduled time, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037527/how-to-get-a-delphi-application-thats-running-to-do-something-at-a-particular. If you're having trouble with the network part, have a look at Indy examples... it's very straightforward to do HTTP requests and download FTP files with it.

Comment: And since you're doing an asynchronous operation, you might want to generate a code at the HTTP GET request, which you can use as a parameter on a later POST request to download the file if it's ready... that would eliminate the need to use FTP.

Comment: @mg30rg - Ah now I get it. Sorry if I've been rude. But I think we  have different ways in  interpreting "AUTOMATE". What I meant was to do the 4 functions (open Twebbrowser-form // start URL // run external PHP-program  // (and later) get the updated XML-file) in ONE (AUTOMATED) function. And it was in making / writing / debugging those functions I need help / links/ examples. (In Indy functions I'm still as Bambi on the Ice. )   - But Again:  Sorry If i've been rude - never meant to be.

Comment: You don't need a web browser, just an HTTP client. Indy has a `TIdHTTP` component for that, as well as a `TIdFTP` component. Use `TIdHTTP.Get()` to send a request to the URL and get the response back, then use `TIdFTP.Get()` to download the XML file.

Comment: @REMY LEBEAU  - Thanks. I'll do that. Found how to Use TidHTTP og have tried tidFTP.. so I guess it'll work. Thanks to everyone... BTW - How do I close this question - or it is done automatically ??

Answer (score 1):

Indy (which ships with Delphi) has `TIdHTTP` and `TIdFTP` components. `Use TIdHTTP.Get()` to send a request to the URL and get the response back, then use `TIdFTP.Get()` to download the XML file.

You can use Windows Task Scheduler to run your app at pre-determined times of the day.  Or have the app running in the background monitoring the clock.  Either way will allow you to control when to call each component.

I would suggest Task Scheduler. If you give your app command-line parameters to tell it what to do, you can then create two separate Tasks, one to run your app in HTTP mode at 10:00, and one to run your app in FTP mode at 10:15.  Let the app exit as soon as it is done with its work. This way, your app is not sitting idle for 99% of the day doing nothing.